# Why does the python os library return an error on one file but not three others?

Tags: python, operating-system

The simple script to collect file names and sizes fails on the 4th file with the following error:

"FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'A023_04.mp3'"

```
import os

siteID = 'A023' #This must match audio and NVSPL directories and filenames
drive_audio = "E"
dirName_audio = drive_audio + ':\\data\\audio\\' + siteID + '\\'

fileNames_MP3 = [file for file in os.listdir(dirName_audio)] 

# this works:
for val in fileNames_MP3:
    print(val)
print('\n')
    
# this works for the first three files:
for val in fileNames_MP3:
    file_stats=os.stat(val)
    print(val, file_stats.st_size)
```

Here is the output:

```
A023_01.mp3
A023_02.mp3
A023_03.mp3
A023_04.mp3


A023_01.mp3 1073672486
A023_02.mp3 1073644272
A023_03.mp3 1073644273
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\data\mp3_garage\funWithFileInfo.py", line 16, in <module>
    file_stats=os.stat(val)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'A023_04.mp3'
```

I am able to view the properties using the Windows file manager, and don't see anything quirky about that particular file compared to the others.

Comment: `os.listdir()` returns only the bare filenames, without the full path.  So when you call `os.stat(val)`, it is looking in the **current directory**.  I'm guessing that whatever the current directory is, it happens to contain the same first three filenames, but not the fourth one.

Comment: You can use this to display the actual current directory `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: The folder that *is* checked for the files *happens to contain* files that match certain of the filenames, but not others. But the code is still looking in the wrong folder, so all of the filenames are "wrong". Please see the linked duplicates for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *first* thing I would do is to print out the length of each `val` as well as the value itself (in the first loop):

```py
print(len(val), val)
```

That's because it's interesting that there are *two* blank lines between the two output chunks.

That *may* have been a transcription error on your part or it may be a file name with weirdly embedded characters.

If the length of the errant file differs from the others, that may be the issue.

---

Also, you specify the full path when getting the list of files but getting status information uses just the file name. If you run your code from a *different* directory that contains files with the names of the first three only, that would also explain what you're seeing.

The fact that your *program* is `E:\data\mp3_garage\funWithFileInfo.py` could indicate that *that* is the directory where you're running the code from.

You could solve that by getting the status with the full path names:

```py
file_stats = os.stat(f"{dirName_audio}val")
```

Comment: yep, transcription error on the extra blank line, but thanks a bunch, for catching the missing path for os.stat()

Comment: @BillH: if that (the missing path) was indeed the problem, you should accept the answer.